# CFDOCUMENT PDF White Space Issue

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, datatable, export

I realize that there are several other posts similar to this one, but I have tried every solution found within them and have not had any luck.  Basically, I have a ColdFusion generated webpage that consists of a jQuery DataTable.  I want to export the contents of the DataTable to PDF, however on certain tables where the table content exceeds the height of the page, the PDF adds my header area and then the rest of the page is blank.  The table then shows up on page 2.  Has anyone had trouble similar to this?

I've tried setting the page size, margins, @imports for the CSS, standard links for the CSS, inline CSS, and nothing seems to fix it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Any suggestions are welcome too!

Comment: You can try using CSS page breaks at certain points. Otherwise, break up the main table into a series of stacked tables without a main wrapping table. The page will break between tables and look more natural.

Comment: What method are you using to export the html to pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ended up fixing this problem for me is I wrote a simple javascript function that takes two parameters, the id of the table requested and the max rows per page.  My javascript function then grabs the entire table, and breaks it into separate tables using the max rows value as the number of rows per table.  I then output the JS variable as the value for the  tag and there are no longer incorrect page breaks.

I hope that in the future the cfdocument tag will be more proficient at knowing when it's reached the end of a page and break the content appropriately, but for now this works.